# Freeware to make vectorial annotation (desktop or online)

Tags: windows-7

I can't find any freeware to make vectorial annotation for picture so that I can easily modify it. Gimp and Inkscape don't really make this easy.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your problems with Inkscape, which is an excellent product.

I hope you understand that one can only add vectorial annotation for a picture that is in a vectorial format to start with.

Some more free vector editors that you can try are:

[DrawPlus](http://www.freeserifsoftware.com/software/DrawPlus/default.asp)
[InsightPoint](http://download.cnet.com/InsightPoint/3000-2191_4-10122526.html)
[Pencil](http://www.pencil-animation.org/)
[Zoner Draw 5](http://www.zoner.com/ww-en/support/downloads/free)

Comment: +1 for Inkscape. Standard raster image file formats like JPEG and PNG don't support vector layers so the lack of ease is not due to the programs mentioned but the file formats themselves. Square peg + round hole.